# How to get controls actual id in Master Page Javascript method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a method that passes the asp.net texbox into a Javascript method. I am trying to get the controls id without the full remaned MasterPage ID.

```
<asp:textbox id="txtName" onblur="RequestFieldOnn(this);" runat="server" />
```

When I do the below I get the full id of the above textbox which has been slightly changed because I am using Master Pages

```
function RequestFieldOnn(x) {
       alert(x.id);       
   }
```

Any idea how I can grab the id as it is initially 'txtName' I know JQuery is the answer I just cant get it right. Something along the lines of...

```
alert(document.getElementById($(x).attr('id')));
```

I don't even need to pass the control I could just pass in the id. It still gives me the full master page ID field.

Thanks in advance for any advice with this.

Comment: jQuery has nothing to do with that. It's all about ASP.NET.

Comment: Read this http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs and go straight to Step 4.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581915/how-to-change-the-value-of-an-asptextbox-from-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Its not about Jquery**

Setting a ClientID property separates the server side and client side ids. You will have client id for client side development which makes code much easier and clean.

```
Markup: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" ClientID="”Echo”" runat="server" 
    ClientIDMode="Static" /> 
Output: <input id="Text2" name="Echo" />
```

Read more at : [ASP.net Client ID](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34151/ASP-NET-Client-ID-Feature)