# only first statement excueted not subsequent...? why..?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
function fieldValidation()
{
        //alert("Email: "+document.getElementById("txbemail1").value);
        var emailExp = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([com\co\.\in])+$/;
        var str = document.getElementById("txbemail1").value;
        var result = "Hello...!";
        if (str != '') 
        {
           if (!(emailExp.test(str))) 
           {
              result += "\n Invalid Email";
           }
        }
        else 
        {
           result += "\n Email1";
        }
        alert("Error Detail: " + result);
}
```

html:

```
  <asp:TextBox ClientIDMode="Static" id="txbemail1" runat="server" Width="150px" OnTextChanged="txbemail1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:Button ID="btnnext" runat="server" OnClientClick="return fieldValidation();" OnClick="btnnext_Click" Text="Next" />
```

when calling javascript function only first statement excuted but not subsequent statement, why this is so...?

Comment: Paste your html as well.

Comment: Till where it's executing ? Share output with us.

Comment: Maybe document.getElementById("txbemail1") returns null so the code breaks with null exception

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txbemail1" ... In asp ID is used for server side.I think asp is geberating a ID form the client side.So there is no text box with ID value txbemail1 at client side.Better chek the source of the web page in browser what is the ID value asp is generating.

Answer (score 0):

[How to change the value of an asp:textbox from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581915/how-to-change-the-value-of-an-asptextbox-from-javascript)

According to this You can set the ClientIDMode attribute to Static so aso will generate same id at client side.

```
<asp:TextBox  ClientIDMode="Static"  ID="txbemail1" 
runat="server" Width="150px"  OnTextChanged="txbemail1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: this work but only display input from textbox and not execuete remaining code

Comment: only first alert statement executed and display result and when i comment that line the subsequent code not work of javascript function...

Comment: I have created a fiddle and it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/9ydn3z3m/ .please update fiddle with your html code generated at client side browser